# References to figures has bad hyperlinks

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, lists, chapters

In my LaTeX document I have some figures. They are automatically numbered using the chapters they are within, for example. Fig 1.1, Fig 2.3 etc. I am using mwart document class.
My problem is that the hyperlinks that are created for some of the figures (using `\ref` and `\listoffigures`) are wrong. For example if i click on the hyperlink that should lead to figure 2.1, it leads me to the 1.1 instead. Same for 2.2 -> 1.2 etc.
What can be the issue here? Just for the sake of testing, I have created some additional dummy figures in chapter 2, so I have more figures there than in chapter 1. When I click on figure 2.7 it takes me to 2.7, since the highest number figure in chapter 1 is only 1.6...
I would really appreciate all help here. Please let me know what additional information is needed to solve this problem and I will provide them.

This is a test document showing the issue:

```
%% Clear sans, courier

% Klasa:
\documentclass[12pt]{mwart}

% Kodowanie:
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Czcionki:
\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans} %% option 'sfdefault' activates Clear Sans as the default text font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[T1]{polski}

% Geometria i style
%\usepackage{showframe} % debug
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,twoside=true,top=20mm,bottom=30mm,inner=35mm,outer=20mm}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{afterpage}

% Grafika
\usepackage{graphicx}

% kody
\usepackage{listings}

% matma
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

% theoremy
\usepackage{amsthm}

% Numerowanie obiektow wedlug rozdzialow
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

% Linki
\usepackage{url}

% Listy
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\ListProperties(Hide=100, Hang=true, Progressive=3ex, Style*=-- ,
Style2*=$\bullet$ ,Style3*=$\circ$ ,Style4*=\tiny$\blacksquare$ )

% Zmienne srodowiskowe:
\newcommand{\insertImg}[3]{
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=50mm]{#1}
    \caption{#2} \flushleft{Źródło: Na podstawie \cite{#3}}
    \label{#1}
\end{figure}
}
\newcommand{\insertImgSetSize}[4]{
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=#2mm]{#1}
    \caption{#3} \flushleft{Źródło: Na podstawie \cite{#4}}
    \label{#1}
\end{figure}
}

% Indeksowanie w pdfie wyjsciowym
\usepackage{hyperref}

% START:
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty} % usun nr strony ze strony tytulowej

\section{test 1}

\insertImg{cat1.png}
    {caption 1}
    {nothing}

\section{test 2}

\insertImg{cat2.png}
    {caption 2}
    {nothing}

link should lead to 2.1 but will lead to 1.1 \ref{cat2.png}.


\afterpage{\null \thispagestyle{empty} \newpage}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Link to the output pdf as I cant add an attachement here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14154631/test.pdf

Comment: As it stands, this is not answerable yet. Please post a document that shows this issue!

Comment: I have added the link to the doc, I had to commit.

Comment: Please prepare a minimal working example and post it as part of the question. External links can break, leaving the question/answer unuseful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The internal `\theH<counter>` is already explained by Christian Hupfer's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/309751/16967). The answer also shows, how to fix it in a general way.

In this case, there is an alternative way.
`hyperref` refines `\@addtoreset`, which is used by `\counterwithin` and `\numberwithin` to support `\theH<counter>`. However, if these commands are used *before* `hyperref` is loaded, the support comes too late. Therefore, an easy fix is to move `\counterwithin` and `\numberwithin` after `hyperref`:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
```

Answer (score 2):

The usual error: `section` resets the figure counter, in this case the `figure` and the `\theHfigure` macro produce a wrong anchor.

Use something like

```
\renewcommand{\theHfigure}{figure.section.\thesection.\thefigure}
```

to cure this, i.e. a `section` number dependent anchor.

In addition, there were some `%` missing in the `\InsertImg{...}`. macros.

```
%% Clear sans, courier

% Klasa:
\documentclass[12pt]{mwart}

% Kodowanie:
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Czcionki:
\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans} %% option 'sfdefault' activates Clear Sans as the default text font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[T1]{polski}

% Geometria i style
%\usepackage{showframe} % debug
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,twoside=true,top=20mm,bottom=30mm,inner=35mm,outer=20mm}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{afterpage}

% Grafika
\usepackage{graphicx}

% kody
\usepackage{listings}

% matma
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

% theoremy
\usepackage{amsthm}

% Numerowanie obiektow wedlug rozdzialow
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}


% Linki
\usepackage{url}

% Listy
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\ListProperties(Hide=100, Hang=true, Progressive=3ex, Style*=-- ,
Style2*=$\bullet$ ,Style3*=$\circ$ ,Style4*=\tiny$\blacksquare$ )

% Zmienne srodowiskowe:
\newcommand{\insertImg}[3]{%
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=50mm]{#1}
    \caption{#2} \flushleft{Źródło: Na podstawie \cite{#3}}
    \label{#1}
\end{figure}
}
\newcommand{\insertImgSetSize}[4]{%
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=#2mm]{#1}
    \caption{#3} \flushleft{Źródło: Na podstawie \cite{#4}}
    \label{#1}
\end{figure}
}

% Indeksowanie w pdfie wyjsciowym
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\theHfigure}{figure.section.\thesection.\thefigure}


% START:
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty} % usun nr strony ze strony tytulowej

\section{test 1}

\insertImg{ente1.jpg}
    {caption 1}
    {nothing}

\section{test 2}

\clearpage

\insertImg{ente2.jpg}
{caption 2}
{nothing}

link should lead to 2.1 but will lead to 1.1 \ref{ente2.jpg}.


\afterpage{\null \thispagestyle{empty} \newpage}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you only please explain why did this fix the issue so I will know how to use it later?

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło: I've added the statement at the top. It's the resetting of the figure counter, i.e. the anchor `figure.1` etc. occurs multiple times, that's why the link lead back to the first figure

Comment: I could not fix the unreferenced cites, however

Comment: The cites work fine, i typed nothing in the examplse as there ware no cites added. Now I understand that renewcommand. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło: I meant, that I can't fix the cites because I don't have the `.bib` sources.

Comment: I understand, but they were working. Only the figures references were problematic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39816/discussion-between-lukasz-przenioslo-and-christian-hupfer).

Comment: For some unknown reason this answer was downvoted -- it shows the general way to cure such problems with counters and links.